# php crashes with no core file and this message : apc_mmap failed

Tags: linux, php, alternative-php-cache

### Description of the problem

Regularly, cron php processes crash on our production server, which result in mails with the following body :

> PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mmap failed: in Unknown on line 0
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I think the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` should result in core files being handled by apport and then written in `/var/crashes`, but the files I can see there are there since yesterday, although the last crash occured today :

```
-rw-r----- 1 root        whoopsie  1138528 mai   22 04:09 _usr_bin_php5.0.crash
-rw-r----- 1 frontoffice whoopsie  1166373 mai   20 18:00 _usr_bin_php5.1005.crash
-rw-r----- 1 frontoffice whoopsie 81622658 mai   22 00:05 _usr_sbin_php5-fpm.1005.crash
```

I tried to download the last one anyway, and ran `gdb /usr/sbin/php5-fpm /tmp/_usr_sbin_php5-fpm.1005.crash`, only to be told that the file is not a core file (its format was not recognized).

Here is the server's apc configuration :

```
cat /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-apc.ini 
extension=apc.so
apc.shm_size=512M
apc.ttl=3600                   
apc.user_ttl=3600                
apc.enable_cli=1
```

I'm mostly worried about the `apc.shm_size`… isn't it too high or too low ? I understand it has to do with the size of memory segments.

### Question(s)

1. What could be the problem ?
2. How can I troubleshoot it (how can I get
   a valid core file ?) ?

### System information

```
free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       5081296    4354684     726612          0     374744     959968
-/+ buffers/cache:    3019972    2061324
Swap:       522236     516888       5348

cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"

php -v
PHP 5.4.17-1~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jul 17 2013 18:14:06) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

`php -i` excerpt :

```
Configuration

apc

APC Support => enabled
Version => 3.1.13
APC Debugging => Disabled
MMAP Support => Enabled
MMAP File Mask =>  
Locking type => pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support => php
Revision => $Revision: 327136 $
Build Date => Nov 20 2012 18:41:36

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
apc.canonicalize => On => On
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.file_md5 => Off => Off
apc.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
apc.filters => no value => no value
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.include_once_override => Off => Off
apc.lazy_classes => Off => Off
apc.lazy_functions => Off => Off
apc.max_file_size => 1M => 1M
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.num_files_hint => 1000 => 1000
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.report_autofilter => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => default => default
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 512M => 512M
apc.shm_strings_buffer => 4M => 4M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.stat => On => On
apc.stat_ctime => Off => Off
apc.ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.user_entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.user_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.write_lock => On => On



 php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
memcache
memcached
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39531
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39531
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

Comment: `/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c`

Comment: There should be a pipe symbol as the first character, is that not the case?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed it when copy/pasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core file needs to be read on a system that is at least very similar to the one where the crash happened.  In particular you need to have the same versions of the binary and all involved libraries in order for the pointers to line up.  Usually it's easiest to run gdb on the machine where the crash happened.  You'll also need to have versions of the binary and libraries installed that have the symbolic data you need to identify locations in the source files where things happened. That might mean the dev versions of the various libraries, but It depends what distribution of linux you run.

Are you sure you have the right version of APC installed?  Eg it solved this person's problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756385/php-fatal-error-php-startup-apc-mmap-mmap-failed-in-unknown-on-line-0

Is APC failing for web processes as well as command line ones?  If it only fails for one of those, then check that both php packages are the correct versions to work with your version of APC.

The first two dump files you listed look very small to me.  Just over 1 MB.  PHP would usually get bigger than that before it gets as far as running any of your code.  That's likely consistent with failing before loading the code though, and given APC is involved, that's likely.  The fpm one is a web process, not a cron job (unless your cron calls php via the web interface?)

Setting apc.shm_size to 512MB may or not be optimal for efficiency, but I wouldn't expect it to be the cause of a segfault.  Corrupt data in your APC cache could conceivably be the problem though, so I suggest you clear the cache.  The normal process is to use an apc.php file which is likely distributed with apc.  Vendor distributions vary on that, but it is included with the upstream source code, so you should be able to get a copy easily enough.  That gives you a web interface for looking at the state of your cache, and for clearing it.  If APC is failing to the point where that doesn't work, I'm not sure what the process is. Probably locate the cache, delete it, and reinstall APC if needed to rebuild it.  (kinda dirty approach, but low effort if you can afford a brief outage).

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. I think apc is failing for web processes only. I think the fpm crash is from an unrelated crash. I clear the cache the hard way : `php5-fpm reload` does the trick because we set the cache to be shared between the CLI and the FPM versions. I talked with my both and he said we're going to upgrade soon to Ubuntu 14.04 (with newer php and apc versions). But your answer says the a greate deal about gdb and core files, so accepted and bounty granted. Thanks!

Comment: While not what you asked, it's worth noting that apc.php is the tool to look at for things like your cache hit rate, which is important for deciding if you have a sensible size apc.shm_size setting for efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

This should really be a comment, but it's a bit long

> isn't it too high or too low ?

If you don't know how, then how should we? You haven't told us how much RAM and swap there is, how much is used for other stuff. You haven't told us [how much of the APC memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446751/how-to-get-graphs-about-apc-info-in-php) is used before the system crashes.

> file is not a core file (its format was not recognized).

Have you checked the ulimit? Most likely the file has been truncated. Regardless, a segmentation fault suggests an issue within PHP itself (or APC, or an extension). Were you planning on fixing it yourself? Don't get me wrong - the guys who write the stuff will welcome well researched and documented bug reports - but the first thing you should be looking at (and including in your question here) is the version of PHP, the extensions installed and the version of APC.

Comment: I knew my question lacked information, but I had no idea what would matter and what wouldn't. I'm going to provide it, and then, if nothing looks obviously wrong with it, I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Also, I'd like to have a core file to attach to my bug report, this is an important part of my question.

Comment: Regarding the `ulimit` what does it have to do exactly with the problem ? I don't know `ulimit` well…

Comment: `man ulimit` is a good place to start. A core file won't be very welcome on a bug report - just the stack trace.

Comment: I had a look at it before posting the last comment, but I still don't get what limit I should change, and what file you're talking about when you say "the file has been truncated". As per the stack trace, I don't have one, that's why I'm a bit reluctant to file a bug report. Technically, I do have one, but "in Unknown on line 0" is not really helpful, is it ?

Comment: So, any ideas about the unrecognized core file problem (or anything else ?)

Comment: If `ulimit -c` returns 0 then you aren't writing out core file